# Finding $(i, i)$-entry of $AB$ triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ and $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}$ be two upper triangular matrices, i.e. $a_{ij}=b_{ij}=0$ whenever $i>j$.
>
> $(a)$ Show that the $(i,j)$-entry of $AB$ is $0$ if $i>j$, i.e $AB$ is an upper triangular matrix.
>
> $(b)$ Find the $(i,i)$-entry of $AB$.

I have already proven part (a). How do I go about finding part (b)? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(AB)_{11} = a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12} \underbrace{b_{21}}_{\text{zero}} + \dots + a_{1n} \underbrace{b_{n1}}_{\text{zero}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the formula for the entry of the product of two matrices:
$$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{r=1}^{n}A_{ir}B_{rj}.$$

If you are having trouble finding a nice answer for this, try a $3\times 3$ matrix example to get an idea of what is going on.